# FormControl validator result in TypeError cannot read property of undefined

Tags: angular, formgroups

My users are allowed to enter only specific values to an input of text type.

Here is the app.component.ts:

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  myForm: FormGroup;
  allowedValuesArray = ['Foo', 'Boo'];

  ngOnInit() {
    this.myForm = new FormGroup({
      'foo': new FormControl(null, [this.allowedValues])
    });        
  }

  allowedValues(control: FormControl): {[s: string]: boolean} {
    if (!this.allowedValuesArray.indexOf(control.value)) {
      return {'notValidFoo': true};
    }        
    return {'notValidFoo': false};
  }
}
```

The app.component.html:

```
<form [formGroup]="myForm">
  Foo: <input type="text" formControlName="foo">
  <span *ngIf="!myForm.get('foo').valid">Not valid foo</span>
</form>
```

On page load it throw this exception:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'allowedValuesArray' of undefined
>       at push../src/app/app.component.ts.AppComponent.allowedValues (app.component.ts:20)
>       at forms.js:1170
>       at Array.map ()
>       at _executeValidators (forms.js:1170)
>       at FormControl.validator (forms.js:1132)
>       at FormControl.push../node_modules/@angular/forms/fesm5/forms.js.AbstractControl._runValidator
>   (forms.js:2931)
>       at FormControl.push../node_modules/@angular/forms/fesm5/forms.js.AbstractControl.updateValueAndValidity
>   (forms.js:2907)
>       at new FormControl (forms.js:3267)
>       at AppComponent.push../src/app/app.component.ts.AppComponent.ngOnInit
>   (app.component.ts:15)
>       at checkAndUpdateDirectiveInline (core.js:21097)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like KamLar said, it comes from this line:

```
if (!this.allowedValuesArray.indexOf(control.value)) {
  return {'nameIsForbidden': true};
}
```

you can handle it with

```
'foo': new FormControl(null, [this.allowedValues.bind(this)])
```

Answer (score 1):

It comes from this line and how `this` keyword works:

```
if (!this.allowedValuesArray.indexOf(control.value)) {
  return {'nameIsForbidden': true};
}
```

You are not executing method (or function) by yourself, you just let Angular execute it and validate field. Since you are letting to do it to Angular, the `this` is no longer referencing to `AppComponent`. What you have to do is `.bind` `AppComponent` to function, or I believe replace it with arrow style functions like this:

```
fun = (formControl: FormControl) => null
```