# FormControl validator always invalid

Tags: javascript, angular, formgroups

Following my previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60816608/6844481), I'm trying to create a custom validator that allow the users to type only specific values in an input of text.

app.component.ts:

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  myForm: FormGroup;
  allowedValuesArray = ['Foo', 'Boo'];

  ngOnInit() {
    this.myForm = new FormGroup({
      'foo': new FormControl(null, [this.allowedValues.bind(this)])
    });        
  }

  allowedValues(control: FormControl): {[s: string]: boolean} {
    if (this.allowedValuesArray.indexOf(control.value)) {
      return {'notValidFoo': true};
    }        
    return {'notValidFoo': false};
  }
}
```

app.component.html:

```
<form [formGroup]="myForm">
  Foo: <input type="text" formControlName="foo">
  <span *ngIf="!myForm.get('foo').valid">Not valid foo</span>
</form>
```

The problem is that the `foo` FormControl is always false, (the `myForm.get('foo').valid` is always false).

[image]

What wrong with my implementation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you just need to return null when validation is ok. and change that method like below

```
private allowedValues: ValidatorFn (control: FormControl) => {
    if (this.allowedValuesArray.indexOf(control.value) !== -1) {
        return {'notValidFoo': true};
    }
    return null;    
}
```

Comment: good answer!, it is strange to return `{'notValidFoo': false}` in case of not valid foo. did you omit the bind(this) by purpose? it throws exception without its context.

Comment: No, I thought that function was called in the context. :) Happy coding