# FormControl How to fine tune the error validation message to be more specific

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-reactive-forms

Following my previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60818785/6844481) my goal is to show an exact custom error message for an input, so instead of promoting the user with a generic message version, I would like to promote him with a more specific message.

For instance, if it is a number field, and the user is allowed only to enter numbers only within the range of 30 - 40, so if the user has entered 41 than instead of just promoting him with **"Not valid number"** I would like to promote him with a **"You have entered a number that is to big"**, and if he has entered 29 than I would like to promote him **"You have entered a number that is to small"**.

Using the reactive approach this is what I tried to do:

`app.component.html`:

```
<form [formGroup]="myForm">
  FooNumber: <input type="text" formControlName="fooNumber">
  <span *ngIf="!myForm.get('fooNumber').valid">Not valid number, please provide different value</span>
</form>
```

`app.component.ts:`

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  myForm: FormGroup;
  max = 40;
  min = 30;      

  ngOnInit() {
    this.myForm = new FormGroup({
      'fooNumber': new FormControl(null, [this.validateFunction.bind(this)])
    });        
  }
  validateFunction(control: FormControl): {[s: string]: boolean} {
    if (control.value > this.max || control.value < this.min)
      return {'notValidFooNumber': true};

    return null;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key concepts here is to work properly with this return statement:  `return {'notValidFooNumber': true};` it return a key value pair that will populate the `errors`'s list property of the FormGroup object.

The [errors](https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl#errors) property is a:

> An object containing any errors generated by failing validation, or
>   null if there are no errors.

So we could easily initiate the FormGroup's errors with a custom keys such as '`MaxRuleValidation`' and '`MinRuleValidation`' with value of true, and doing a ngIf with `*ngIf="myForm.get('fooNumber').errors['MaxRuleValidation']"` for each one of the keys with a custom error message.

`app.component.ts:`

```
validateFunction(control: FormControl): {[s: string]: boolean} {
  if (control.value > this.max)
    return {'MaxRuleValidation': true};        
  else if (control.value < this.min) 
    return {'MinRuleValidation': true};

  return null; // If there is no error at al the errors list should be null.
}
```

`app.component.html:`

```
<form [formGroup]="myForm">
  FooNumber: <input type="text" formControlName="fooNumber">
  <span *ngIf="!myForm.get('fooNumber').valid">Not valid foo number: 
    <span *ngIf="myForm.get('fooNumber').errors['MaxRuleValidation']">You have entered a number that is to big</span>
    <span *ngIf="myForm.get('fooNumber').errors['MinRuleValidation']">You have entered a number that is to small</span>
  </span>
</form>
```